# Colors in color bar sticking out using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting four (and also eight) subplots next to each other with no whitespace. I also need a color bar which is placed to the far right. However, the colors inside the color bar are out of bounds of the color bar edges: it is sticking out at the top and are not covering the bottom.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, figsize=(4*6.4, 4.8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 4, hspace=.0, wspace=.0) #height_ratios=[1,2,3,4])

for idx, _ in enumerate(ax):
    ax[idx] = plt.subplot(gs[idx])
    sc = plt.scatter(0.5, 0.5)
    ax[idx].xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
    ax[idx].yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
    yticks = ax[idx].get_yticklabels()
    yticks[-1].set_visible(False)
    yticks[0].set_visible(False)
    xticks = ax[idx].get_xticklabels()
    yticks[-1].set_visible(False)
    xticks[0].set_visible(False)

cb_ax = fig.add_axes([ax[3].get_position().x1+0.005,ax[3].get_position().y0,0.01,ax[3].get_position().y1-ax[3].get_position().y0])
cb=fig.colorbar(sc, cax=cb_ax)

plt.show()

fig.savefig('sticking_out.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

In the minimal working example, I tried to fit the color bar to the height of the figure. The edge of the color bar is perfectly aligned but the colors themselves are shifted upwards (see images below).

[image]

[image]

Is there an elegant solution to this problem? Perhaps it is also a better way to fit the color bar to the height of the figure?

Comment: It seems to have been affected by the`bbox_inches='tight'`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @r-beginners. If I remove `bbox_inches='tight` it is still there but less visible.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.   Running on windows10, matplotlib 3.3.4, pycharm. But I do get similar problems if I decrease the default dpi (e.g. `fig.savefig('sticking_out.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=50)`). So, you might try to increase the dpi.

Comment: Thank you, @JohanC. It does appear to improve with choosing a nondefault and high `dpi`. Do have any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: This will be rounding errors. The lower the dpi the less dots to place vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @JohanC for explaining it to me in the comments above. It is solved if use you a higher `dpi` and it is caused by rounding errors, according to @JohanC. I answered the question myself to "close" it but all credit to @JohanC.